# Multiple Footer/Header via CSS in 1 DIV

Tags: javascript, html, css, header, footer

I generate a PDF File from a HTML Source. Each Page has a height of 1402px. First solution was, a DIV for each side.Placing Footer and Header was easy then. Problem is: if the content (dynamically generated) doesn't fit the page div, it overlaps the footer and in worst case, destroys the layout. So all the Pages and their content goes into one div, but how do i add 300px of margin, which I need for Footer and Header?

I tried to display my problem in this picture:

The whole white thing is one Div.
The black lines display each page in the Div but they are not in the code.
The green lines display where I need a margin so the red content doesn't overlap, but continues on the second page instead.

```
Red -> current situation
Blue -> what I need
```

I can also use Javascript in the document.

Can you help me?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMFBb.png

Here is the fiddle of how its solved until now:

https://jsfiddle.net/8yvpavd7/1/

Comment: Please post some code.

Comment: we will need to get a bit more information on your data and coding - how is the content structured? Can you cut it into smaller pieces?

Comment: where does the data come from? how is it structured? plain text?

Comment: thx for the example, but from this i can't see your problem or how the data is retreived. Do you have a specific json structure or how do you transform your data into html code

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you ensure that the height of your page is lower than a specific limit. Since you are using absolute sizes and positioning anyway you can easily check that using jquery (example:)

```
$('#page1').height()  /  $('#page1').outerHeight()
```

Since we don't know anything about your datastructure, i can only assume what you need. The following fiddle should explain what i'm talking about https://jsfiddle.net/rkvs5s1z/2/

You could remove parts of your content until it fits the height. You need to store the removed data.
**The fiddle does not store the data in the correct direction - it should only demonstrate how this could work**

Afterwards you append a new page including your headers and footers.

You might need to repeat these steps if the content of one page is bigger than two pages.

I would also suggest to improve the shown example by not slicing single characters but complete words. If your pages contain html you might also need to check for html code and correct nesting.